# Check icon in menu

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have been developing a windows application. I had built a menu bar. When I click on the menu option once, it show a checked sign. But again when I click on the same option the check sign does not goes off.

The code I had written is:

```
nmviewtextbox.Checked = !nmviewtextbox.Checked;
```

but its showing an error

Comment: Mind telling us what the error is? [Edit] that into your question, please.

Comment: What's the error it shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are calling this code from the `CheckedChanged` event and thus you are provoking an endless loop (this event is called every time `nmviewtextbox.Checked` is changed). In that case, delete this line (the method would continue working without any problem).

Otherwise (outside the event triggered when `.Checked` is changed), this code should work fine.

Bear in mind that, as suggested by Cody Gray, you can disable the check-on-click functionality (and thus allow this line of code to work without triggering any error).

Comment: You're probably right about the source of the error. If the [`CheckOnClick` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.checkonclick.aspx) is enabled, he doesn't need to write any code at all.

Comment: @CodyGray is a typical novice error. Bear in mind that this property is enabled by default (and used in most of the codes, anyway).